# Sound.Pulse.Simple not working?

Tags: haskell, audio

I downloaded [Sound.Pulse.Simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pulse-simple-0.1.11/docs/Sound-Pulse-Simple.html) and copy and pasted the example program:

```
main=do
  s<-simpleNew Nothing "example" Play Nothing "this is example application"
      (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1) Nothing Nothing
  simpleWrite s [sin $ 2*pi*440*(t/44100)|t<-[1..44100*10]]
  simpleDrain s
  simpleFree s
```

into atom and tried to compile it just to make sure it would work on my system. ghc is really upset, here's the full error message (even though it's obscenely long):

```
soundtest.hs:6:5:
No instance for (Foreign.Storable.Storable a0)
  arising from a use of `simpleWrite'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Foreign.Storable.Storable BufferAttr -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Foreign.Storable.Storable Sound.ChannelMap
    -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Foreign.Storable.Storable SampleSpec -- Defined in `Sound'
  ...plus 45 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  simpleWrite
    s [sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100) | t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]]
In the expression:
  do { s <- simpleNew
              Nothing
              "example"
              Play
              Nothing
              "this is example application"
              (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1)
              Nothing
              Nothing;
       simpleWrite
         s [sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100) | t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]];
       simpleDrain s;
       simpleFree s }
In an equation for `main':
    main
      = do { s <- simpleNew
                    Nothing
                    "example"
                    Play
                    Nothing
                    "this is example application"
                    (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1)
                    Nothing
                    Nothing;
             simpleWrite
               s [sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100) | t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]];
             simpleDrain s;
             .... }

soundtest.hs:6:20:
No instance for (Floating a0) arising from a use of `sin'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include t :: a0 (bound at soundtest.hs:6:45)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Floating Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Floating Foreign.C.Types.CFloat
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  ...plus one other
In the expression: sin
In the expression: sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100)
In the second argument of `simpleWrite', namely
  `[sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100) | t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]]'

soundtest.hs:6:37:
No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of `/'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include t :: a0 (bound at soundtest.hs:6:45)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Fractional Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Fractional Foreign.C.Types.CFloat
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus two others
In the second argument of `(*)', namely `(t / 44100)'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100)'
In the expression: sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100)

soundtest.hs:6:48:
No instance for (Enum a0)
  arising from the arithmetic sequence `1 .. 44100 * 10'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Enum ChannelPosition -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Enum Direction -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Enum SampleFormat -- Defined in `Sound'
  ...plus 45 others
In the expression: [1 .. 44100 * 10]
In a stmt of a list comprehension: t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]
In the second argument of `simpleWrite', namely
  `[sin $ 2 * pi * 440 * (t / 44100) | t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]]'

soundtest.hs:6:49:
No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `1'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Foreign.C.Types.CChar -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Num Foreign.C.Types.CClock -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Num Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  ...plus 38 others
In the expression: 1
In the expression: [1 .. 44100 * 10]
In a stmt of a list comprehension: t <- [1 .. 44100 * 10]

soundtest.hs:6:5:
No instance for (Foreign.Storable.Storable a0)
  arising from a use of `simpleWrite'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Foreign.Storable.Storable BufferAttr -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Foreign.Storable.Storable Sound.ChannelMap
    -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Foreign.Storable.Storable SampleSpec -- Defined in `Sound'
  ...plus 45 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  simpleWrite
    s
    [sin $ 2.0 * pi * 440.0 * (t / 44100.0) |
       t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]]
In the expression:
  do { s <- simpleNew
              Nothing
              "example"
              Play
              Nothing
              "this is example application"
              (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1)
              Nothing
              Nothing;
       simpleWrite
         s
         [sin $ 2.0 * pi * 440.0 * (t / 44100.0) |
            t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]];
       simpleDrain s;
       simpleFree s }
In an equation for `main':
    main
      = do { s <- simpleNew
                    Nothing
                    "example"
                    Play
                    Nothing
                    "this is example application"
                    (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1)
                    Nothing
                    Nothing;
             simpleWrite
               s
               [sin $ 2.0 * pi * 440.0 * (t / 44100.0) |
                  t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]];
             simpleDrain s;
             .... }

soundtest.hs:6:20:
No instance for (Floating a0) arising from a use of `sin'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include t :: a0 (bound at soundtest.hs:6:51)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Floating Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Floating Foreign.C.Types.CFloat
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  ...plus one other
In the expression: sin
In the expression: sin $ 2.0 * pi * 440.0 * (t / 44100.0)
In the second argument of `simpleWrite', namely
  `[sin $ 2.0 * pi * 440.0 * (t / 44100.0) |
      t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]]'

soundtest.hs:6:54:
No instance for (Enum a0)
  arising from the arithmetic sequence `1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Enum ChannelPosition -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Enum Direction -- Defined in `Sound'
  instance Enum SampleFormat -- Defined in `Sound'
  ...plus 45 others
In the expression: [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]
In a stmt of a list comprehension:
  t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]
In the second argument of `simpleWrite', namely
  `[sin $ 2.0 * pi * 440.0 * (t / 44100.0) |
      t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]]'

soundtest.hs:6:55:
No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from the literal `1.0'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Fractional Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Fractional Foreign.C.Types.CFloat
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus two others
In the expression: 1.0
In the expression: [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]
In a stmt of a list comprehension:
  t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]

soundtest.hs:6:71:
No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `*'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Foreign.C.Types.CChar -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Num Foreign.C.Types.CClock -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Num Foreign.C.Types.CDouble
    -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  ...plus 38 others
In the expression: 44100.0 * 10.0
In the expression: [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]
In a stmt of a list comprehension:
  t <- [1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]
```

I tried switching everything to a `Float` (even though that risks floating point imprecision with the range) and it still won't compile. Is there another library I have to download or something? Is there a different library for sound output I should be using? I'm on windows and using the Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0

Comment: Which types GHC says that are missing instances? I suggest you edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: @duplode Just did

Comment: Do you have pulseAudio installed?  Might have an easier time on Windows with DirectSound.

Comment: @ja. The issue described in the question isn't related to PulseAudio.

Answer (score 1):

The "ambiguous type variable" errors mean that there wasn't enough information for the type checker to decide which type it should use to instantiate the type classes. To fix that, add a type annotation that specifies the type of the list elements, such as:

```
simpleWrite s ([sin $ 2*pi*440*(t/44100)|t<-[1..44100*10]] :: [Float])
```

(The example in the [documentation for the latest version of the library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pulse-simple-0.1.14/docs/Sound-Pulse-Simple.html), unlike the one you linked to, does include the missing annotation.)

There are a few things left to explain, though. Firstly, you mention that you tried to fix the error by "switch[ing] everything to a Float". I suppose this attempt corresponds to the second set of errors you included, and that you changed `[1 .. 44100 * 10]` to `[1.0, 2.0 .. 44100.0 * 10.0]` and so forth. If that is indeed the case, it didn't work because adding a decimal point doesn't actually change the type to `Float`, because Haskell numeric literals are polymorphic:

```
GHCi> :t 1
1 :: Num t => t
GHCi> :t 1.0
1.0 :: Fractional t => t
```

That also means that even in the absence of the type annotation the range in `[sin $ 2*pi*440*(t/44100)|t<-[1..44100*10]]` generates floating point values, as if that weren't the case there would be no way to use them with `sin` and `(/)`. While in your case there is no risk of inaccuracy as far as the range is concerned (that problem only arises with step sizes that aren't whole numbers, or, for different reasons, with very large numbers), using e.g. `Integer`s for the range is possible as long as you introduce a suitable conversion function:

```
[sin $ 2*pi*440*(fromInteger t/44100)|t<-[1..44100*10]]
```

Secondly, you might wonder why you got ambiguity errors this time, given that you have been using those polymorphic literals with no issues beforehand. You don't usually get such errors because there is a defaulting mechanism for polymorphic numbers that, in ambiguous cases, picks whichever of `Integer` or `Double` is more appropriate (see the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) for details). This mechanism, however, only kicks in if the classes the polymorphic number calls for are drawn from a limited set of standard classes -- which makes sense, as if you are using more exotic classes the odds of the guess by the compiler being inappropriate increase. Now, if you look at the type of `simpleWrite`...

```
simpleWrite :: Storable a => Simple -> [a] -> IO ()
```

... you will note that it requires `Storable`. `Storable` is not among the aforementioned set of standard classes, and so there is no defaulting.

Comment: This solved that problem, but now I've run into another issue I've never had to deal with before: a linking error due to "undefined references" to `pa_simple_free`, `pa_simple_get_latency`, etc. Wasn't sure if I should start a new question over this so I figured I'd just check if there was a quick fix in the comments

Comment: @EbenCowley Being an unrelated issue, it should go to a new question. (I'm afraid I can't help much with it, other than noting that these are functions from the [C PulseAudio library](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/pulseaudio/doxygen/simple_8h.html), and so you'll probably want to begin by checking whether that is properly installed in your system.)